# Check if 1 string out of 3 has value

Tags: c#

I have 3 strings and I have to check that only 1 of them has a value.

This is my Solution:

```
string x;
string y;
string z;

//Logic here

if (!x.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && y.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && z.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    
}
else if (x.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && !y.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && z.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{

}
else if (x.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && y.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && !z.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{

}
else
{
    //Case I am searching
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: "Case I am searching" is reached when either 0 or more than 1 has a value; not clear if that is what you want.

Comment: Can you guarantee that only one of `x`, `y` or `z` will ever be not empty. That else will capture cases where 2, 3 or none of them are not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which one has text, you can simply do this:

```
string a = "";
string b = null;
string c = "";

var stringsWithText =
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a) ? 0 : 1) +
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b) ? 0 : 1) +
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c) ? 0 : 1);

if (stringsWithText == 1)
{
    // Only one string has text.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a method taking `params string[]`

```
static bool HasOneValue(params string?[] items)
{
    if (items.Length == 0)
        return false;
    
    var nonEmptyCounter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[i]))
            continue;
        
        nonEmptyCounter++;
        if (nonEmptyCounter > 1)
            return false;
    }
    
    return nonEmptyCounter == 1;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHi5L4

Answer (score 0):

```
if (new string[] {x,y,z}).Count(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) == 1) {

}
```

I find that with specific logical combinations, LINQ expressions are usually the easiest to read, and don't require an extra method that only gets used in a single line.